# Differences Between Two Different Create Index Commands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

Are there differences between these two scripts?  Or would all of the extra tokens/attributes (ie: `NONCLUSTERED`, `WITH...`, etc...) for the 1<sup>st</sup> script be defaults in SQL Server 2008 for the 2<sup>nd</sup> script?

#### 1<sup>st</sup> script:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DEID_MAP_IDX1] ON [dbo].[DEID_MAP]
(
    [VISIT_NUM] ASC
) WITH 
  (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
   STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
   IGNORE_DUP_KEY  = OFF, 
   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

#### 2<sup>nd</sup> script:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [DEID_MAP_IDX1] ON [DEID_MAP] 
(
    [VISIT_NUM] ASC
);
```

FYI: there is ETL code that drops the index with this script before doing a bulk data load, and then finally applying re-creating the index with the 2nd script above.

```
DROP INDEX [deid_map_idx1] ON [deid_map] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF );
```

---

**EDIT:**

**After applying the simple index above (2nd script), I got this:**

SQL Server Management Studio > expanded table > expanded folder "Indexes" > right click index > selected "Script Index as.." > selected "CREATE TO" > selected "New Query Editor Window" > got the following.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DEID_MAP_IDX1] ON [dbo].[DEID_MAP] 
(
    [VISIT_NUM] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**So it appears that these are added in addition by running the simple statement:**

SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF

DROP_EXISTING = OFF

ONLINE = OFF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It boils down to looking what the default values are.  Lets break this down:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [DEID_MAP_IDX1] ON [dbo].[DEID_MAP]
```

`nonclustered` is specified here.  The default (i.e. nothing specified) is `nonclustered`.  So unless `clustered` is specified it will default to `nonclustered`.  So that's the same in both scripts.

`[dbo]` is specified here explicitly.  As for the second un-specified `CREATE INDEX` then it all depends on what the current user's default schema is.  Only you can answer that at the moment, so that may or may not default to `dbo`.

```
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY  = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`PAD_INDEX`: the default is `OFF`, so unspecified will be the same in the second script as it is in the first.

`STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE`: the default is `OFF`, so the second script unspecified has the same value.

`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`: the default is `OFF`, so the second `CREATE INDEX` is identical with this parameter.

`ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS`: the default is `ON`, so the second `CREATE` script has the same behavior.

`ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS`: the default is `ON`...the second script has identical behavior.

`... ON [PRIMARY]`: just like the default schema one, this all depends on what your default filegroup is.  If `PRIMARY` is the default filegroup, your second `CREATE INDEX` script will also create the index on `PRIMARY`.  If `PRIMARY` is **not** the default filegroup, then it will be a different filegroup, as an unspecified filegroup will go to the default filegroup.

All of this information and default values can be found on [this BOL reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 - Much better detail than my answer

Comment: My actual issue wasn't that they were different.  It was that in our ETL code, it was trying to drop an index that didn't exist.  We renamed a table, and never created the new index based on that name.  The T-SQL script in our ETL code couldn't find the index to drop.  But thanks for the detail.  I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is one big difference.

**`[dbo]` is not necessarily the default schema for every user.**  The second script could be affecting an entirely different table.  It is definitely a good practice to always specify a schema.

The other options, specifically in the `WITH` are all SQL Server defaults, besides the `PRIMARY` file group which is defaulted at the database level. There may be a way to change these default values, though.

As a rule, it's always a good idea to specify these options in production scripts since it makes it clear what the setting is.  Not everyone knows the default for every setting and making it explicit is very clear.